# NoClassDefFoundError on Spigot plugin trying to include Apache Commons Text

Tags: java, gradle, bukkit

I'm writing a Spigot plugin where I need to use Levenshtein distance so I'm using Apache Commons Text 1.8

When I export the plugin and try to run it, I get a NoClassDefFoundError where I instantiate the LevenshteinDistance object.

I'm using Gradle to setup the dependencies.

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }

     maven {
        url "https://repo.dmulloy2.net/nexus/repository/public/"
     }
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compileOnly 'org.bukkit:bukkit:1.15.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT';
    compileOnly 'com.comphenix.protocol:ProtocolLib:4.5.0';
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.8';
}
```

Error

```
[15:06:10] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling CubeChat v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/similarity/LevenshteinDistance
        at com.cubepalace.cubechat.listeners.FilterListener.<init>(FilterListener.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at com.cubepalace.cubechat.CubeChat.register(CubeChat.java:71) ~[?:?]
        at com.cubepalace.cubechat.CubeChat.onEnable(CubeChat.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:432) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at com.rylinaux.plugman.util.PluginUtil.load(PluginUtil.java:366) [PlugMan.jar:?]
        at com.rylinaux.plugman.command.LoadCommand.execute(LoadCommand.java:114) [PlugMan.jar:?]
        at com.rylinaux.plugman.PlugManCommandHandler.onCommand(PlugManCommandHandler.java:95) [PlugMan.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:713) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:698) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:443) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:407) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:984) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:824) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.text.similarity.LevenshteinDistance
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:167) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:96) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-8faa8b4-fba9f48]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        ... 18 more
```

How do I pack the required library into the jar so that I can run this? Using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: `I get a NoClassDefFoundError` What is the actual error? You should include it. Most likely you are simply missing a dependency.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Added the error. I know I'm missing the dependency but I just don't know how to include the required library in the packaged jar

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly figured out that the dependency is there at build time but it is not there at runtime.

What you need to do is a process called "shading". There is a Gradle plugin for doing just that.

Here is a link: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/#default-java-groovy-tasks